# Using an IF statement in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm new to R. 
I want to do something along the lines of:

if Survive="Y" then Survive1=1 in my dataframe named "od" 
But, I'm having trouble with the code. This is what I currently have

```
od$Survive <- c(0)
if(od$Survive=="Y"){
  od$Survive1=1
}
```

I keep getting this warning:

> Warning message:
>   In if (od$Survive == "Y") { :
>     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: Do `od$Survive1 <- as.integer(od$Survive=="Y")`

Comment: Not quite clear what you are trying to do. Maybe  just use logical subsetting: `od$Survive1[od$Survive == "Y"] <- 1`, but you should also look into the `ifelse()` *function* rather than the `if ... else` *construct*.

Comment: `ifelse` for vectors, `if` for scalars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are seeing has to do with that an `if` statement is not vectorized, and so R is telling you that only the first element of the vector will be used.  Try using `ifelse` for a vectorized solution:

```
od$Survive1 <- ifelse(od$Survive == "Y", 1, 0)
```

You could also just assign to the boolean expression:

```
od$Survive1 <- od$Survive == "Y"
```

Comment: Surely this is duplicate?